# Searching data in my database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, sql-like, oledbcommand

My work here is working but if search 1 it display 40 instead of 900 here is my work:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Computation WHERE Transaction_ID LIKE '" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "%'");

command.Connection = connection;    
connection.Open();  
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();              
while (reader.Read())
{                  
   textBox2.Text = (String.Format("{0000,0:N2}", Int32.Parse(reader["Total_Bill"].ToString())));
}                  
connection.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Why you use `LIKE` here? Because it might get `11` also when you have this `ID`. Just use `SELECT * FROM Computation WHERE Transaction_ID = 1` instead.

Comment: sir @SonerGönül this question is off topic here, how can i select the last data in Transaction_ID?

Comment: You can use a query like `SELECT TOP 1 Transaction_ID FROM Computation ORDER BY Transaction_ID DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote *[in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477568/searching-data-in-my-database#comment28886456_19477568)*, I don't understand why you used `LIKE` here but you can [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) which is perfect in your situation.

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query.

Like;

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = ("SELECT Total_Bill FROM Computation WHERE Transaction_ID = @ID");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);    
command.Connection = connection;
try
{    
  connection.Open();  
  textBox2.Text = (String.Format("{0000,0:N2}", command.ExecuteScalar()));            
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}                 
connection.Close();
```